# Do we want a gutenberg tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just found a few questions being tagged [gutenberg](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gutenberg) an hour ago. Not sure if this is needed as it also sounds a bit off-topic to me.

Comment: Since those questions put _Gutenberg_ in the title, I would say it's not necessary. We have [tag:wysiwyg] already for those type of editors.